# Keras fit_generator raise You must compile your model before using it Error

Tags: keras, lstm

I try to build a CNN + LSTM model by Keras to train a model for video classification task. Firstly, A simple model was built and trained with mock data, 'fit()' api, also it works!

But actually, what is used to train this model is a  video dataset, it's so big that can't be loaded into memory. so I need a generator, in this place, I also write a mock generator which generate data with shape same as mock data method. Also, fit_generator API replaces fit.

When I run train_gen function, I get following error:

```
File "lstm.py", line 48, in <module>
    train_gen()
  File "lstm.py", line 45, in train_gen
    model.fit_generator(data_generator.mock_generator(batch_size=32, num_classes=16), steps_per_epoch=1000, epochs=20)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/legacy/interfaces.py", line 91, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1415, in fit_generator
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training_generator.py", line 39, in fit_generator
    model._make_train_function()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 485, in _make_train_function
    raise RuntimeError('You must compile your model before using it.')
RuntimeError: You must compile your model before using it.
```

I tried to solve this problem by searching in stack overflow and google, and do not find exact solution. There are some similar questions can be solved by specifying LSTM `input_shape` and `output size`, or add `model.compile()`.

The following snippet code is runnable, and completely same as that mentioned above.

```
import keras
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Input, Embedding, LSTM, Dense, Reshape
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten, Activation
from keras.layers.normalization import BatchNormalization
from keras.layers.wrappers import Bidirectional

from keras.optimizers import Adam
import numpy as np
import os, random

os.environ["CUDA_DEVICE_ORDER"] = "PCI_BUS_ID"   # see issue #152
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"] = ""

use_dropout = True
metrics = ['accuracy']

#mock data generator
def mock_generator(batch_size, input_length, input_dims, num_classes=16):
    while True:
        yield np.random.random((batch_size, input_length, input_dims)), keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(num_classes, size=(batch_size, 1)), num_classes=num_classes)

#mock data with shape as data generator
def mock_data(batch_size, input_length, input_dims, num_classes=16):
    if True:
        return np.random.random((batch_size, input_length, input_dims)), keras.utils.to_categorical(np.random.randint(num_classes, size=(batch_size, 1)), num_classes=num_classes)

#construct model, lstm units is fixed
def bi_lstm(input_shape, num_classes=16):
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100, return_sequences=True, activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape), merge_mode='concat'))
    model.add(Bidirectional(LSTM(100, activation='relu', input_shape=(input_shape[0],100), return_sequences=False), merge_mode='concat'))
    if use_dropout:
        model.add(Dropout(0.5))
    model.add(Dense(num_classes))
    model.add(BatchNormalization())
    model.add(Activation('softmax'))
    optimizer = Adam(lr=1e-5, decay=1e-6)
    model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer,
                           metrics=metrics)
    return model

#fit api run successfully
def train():
    input_length=10
    input_dims=128
    num_classes=10
    model = bi_lstm((input_length, input_dims), num_classes)
    x_train, y_train = mock_data(32, input_length, input_dims, num_classes)
    model.fit(x_train, y_train, epochs=20, batch_size=32)

#fit_generator api raise error!
def train_gen():
    input_length=10
    input_dims=128
    num_classes=10
    model = bi_lstm((input_length, input_dims), num_classes)
    generator = mock_generator(32, input_length, input_dims, num_classes)
    model.fit_generator(generator, steps_per_epoch=1000, epochs=20)

#test mock generator function
def test_mock_gen():
    result  = mock_generator(32,10,128,16)
    for i in range(2):
        x, y = result.next()
        print x.shape
        print y.shape

if __name__ == '__main__':
    train()
    train_gen()
    #test_mock_gen()
```

Comment: The error is simple.You must compile first your model and then run model.fit_generator

Comment: there is model.compile() in first snippet @George

Comment: Make sure you have disable `eager execution`, there is a known bug about that : https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/18287

Comment: @user1978965:First you must call `fit`, then `compile` and then `fit_generator`

Comment: @George No, that is completely wrong.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro:Hmm..Why is that?Because that is what I am doing so far and works fine.

Comment: @George In this situation, which data can be used to 'fit' model? can you give me a sample code?

Comment: @George First you compile the model, then train it with either fit or fit_generator.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro:Oh, yes!Sorry, you are right!I just saw my mistake1!I meant first `compile`, then `fit` and then `fit_generator`.You may create a generator for example, where you are doing some data augmentation and call `fit`.Then, you can call `fit_generator`.That's what I had in mind

Comment: @user1978965:The data is ok (x_train, y_train).Or, if you want to use some data augmentation, you fit the augmented data first and then call fit_generator.

Comment: Is this the actual code that you are running? Because the metrics variable is undefined. Please make sure the code in your question matches the one you are running.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro I complement all code,  thank you for help!

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting couldn't be more explicit: **model** has been declared as a **local object on the train() function** and **is not know by the function train_gen()**. Define your model as a global variable (ex. in main) and it will work.